# Значение в столбце равное количеству строк во второй таблице

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Здравствуйте, дорогие форумчане, меня интересует следующее: на форме два компонента DBGrid, две таблицы, связанные через  Master Source, в первой таблице есть столбец "количество", он в свои ячейки должен присваивать число, равное количеству строк во второй таблице. То есть если во второй таблице 4 строки, то в ячейке должно устанавливаться число "4". Возможно ли это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал использовать не T*Table, а T*Query либо T*DataSet
Все точно также связываем через Master Source, после чего в св-ве SQL родительской таблицы пишем:

```
select p.*,(select count(c.id) from child c where c.id_par=p.id)
from parented p
```

у дочерней

```
select * from child where id_par=:id
```

Answer (score 2):

А кто мешает?
Поставьте на форму компонент T*Query (звездочка, так как я не знаю, какой именно тип Вы используете). Привяжите этот компонент к той же базе. А табличку - к этому компоненту.
Теперь дело за малым - написать правильный sql запрос.

```
select count(*) from имя_таблицы
```

осталось сделать T*Query активным и все.

Answer (score 1):

Если таблицы связаны, то можно и по другому сделать: обратиться к свойству подчинённой таблицы (Вашей Table) RecordCount - оно указывает на кол-во записей в таблице, причём, если таблицы связаны, то на кол-во связанных строк со строкой главной таблицы. Затем записать его в таблицу - в нужное поле, как целое число. Но мне не ясно для чего это нужно - количество записей в таблице можно вывести в какой-нибудь Label.